# ‘std::get_time’ has not been declared

Tags: c++, c++11, datetime, gcc, time

I am using get_time() and mtkime() to convert the values of an object of my DateTime class to a unix timestamp so that I can easily compare two instances of my DateTime class. Here is my code for generating the time stamp

### void DateTime::setTimeStamp()

```
stringstream date_ss1;
date_ss1 << (*this);
istringstream date_iss(date_ss1.str());
struct tm date;
date_iss >> get_time( &date, "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M" );
timestamp = mktime( &date );
```

This code compiles and works perfectly on my Mac.
BUT it gives this as the only error when compiling it on a remote server.

```
DateTime.h:40:12: error: ‘std::get_time’ has not been declared
 using std::get_time;
```

The server's compiler has no problem finding mtkime in case that info is of help.

### My Mac compiler version

> Configured with:
>   --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.37) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0 Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

### Server GNU compiler version

> gcc (GCC) 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)

I got the version of the compilers on both my Mac and the remote server by running

```
gcc --version
```

### DateTime.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <exception>    

using std::ostream;
using std::istream;
using std::string;
using std::setfill;
using std::setw;
using std::endl;
using std::stringstream;
using std::istringstream;
using std::cout;
using std::invalid_argument;
using std::exit;
using std::get_time;

/*code*/
```

Comment: Is there a `-std=c++11` somewhere in your many configuration options?

Comment: @StoryTeller How do I do that? I'm a bit of a newbie.

Comment: It's a GCC compiler option. You didn't specify how the server invokes it, but you should make sure it is supplied that option.

Comment: i used g++ -std=c++11 my-file.cpp and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: In mycase, adding `#include <iomanip>` worked successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to successfully compile my code on the server by adding "-std=c++11" to my compiling call. This works:

```
g++ -std=c++11 DateTime.cpp
```